# How to create QUARTER of a DAY from the TIME PART from a DATE TIME STAMP in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set which contains a variable start_time which is a `DateTimeStamp` variable containing values such as :

```
Start_Time
2019-06-19 02:10:52.563
2019-07-24 02:00:05.037
2019-07-31 07:24:44.187
2019-08-11 16:52:24.343
```

What I want to do is to convert each of these timestamp to quarter of a day (i.e. there are 4 quarters of a day made of 6 hours such that quarter one starts from hh:mm:ss as 00:00:00 to 05:59:59 and quarter 2 starts with 06:00:00 ends at 11:59:59 and quarter 3 starts at 12:00:00 ends at 17:59:59 and quarter 4 starts at 18:00:00 to 11:59:59). So the result would look like:

```
Start_Time                 Quarter
2019-06-19 02:10:52.563    Q1
2019-07-24 02:00:05.037    Q1
2019-07-31 07:24:44.187    Q2
2019-08-11 16:52:24.343    Q3
..... and so forth
```

I was able to extract time part from the above data:

```
 SELECT convert(char(8), start_time, 108) [time] from MyTable;
```

But not sure how to get into quarters. Can someone please help?

Comment: I think I can use Case when statement... got it!

Comment: No need for a complicated non-Standard SQL`convert`, you can simply strip iff the date part using `cast(start_time as time)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note the below is for MySQL (incorrect question tag) - An SQL Server solution is further down this answer**

You can achieve this by fetching the `HOUR` of the `start_time` and then using a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT start_time,
       CASE
         WHEN start_hour < 6 THEN 'Q1'
         WHEN start_hour < 12 THEN 'Q2'
         WHEN start_hour < 18 THEN 'Q3'
         ELSE 'Q4'
       END AS `time`
  FROM (
       SELECT start_time,
              HOUR(start_time) AS start_hour
         FROM MyTable
       ) a
```

Outputs:

```
start_time              time
2019-06-19T02:10:53Z    Q1
2019-07-24T02:00:05Z    Q1
2019-07-31T07:24:44Z    Q2
2019-08-11T16:52:24Z    Q3
```

Alternatively, you could use a simple bit of maths to achieve the same:

```
SELECT start_time,
       CONCAT('Q', FLOOR(HOUR(start_time) / 6 + 1)) AS `time`
  FROM  MyTable
```

This just divides the `HOUR` of the `start_time` by 6, adds 1 (so you don't get `Q0`) and uses `FLOOR` to lower it to the nearest integer.

[MySQL sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97e484b/11)

**EDIT Following discussion of RDBMS Tag Incorrect**

Following realisation that you are actually using SQL Server instead of MySQL, find the following that will achieve the same in SQL Server:

```
SELECT start_time,
       CONCAT('Q', FLOOR(DATEPART(HOUR, start_time) / 6 + 1)) AS [time]
  FROM  MyTable
```

Output:

```
start_time              time
2019-06-19T02:10:53Z    Q1
2019-07-24T02:00:05Z    Q1
2019-07-31T07:24:44Z    Q2
2019-08-11T16:52:24Z    Q3
```

[SQL Server sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/97e48/3)

Comment: I also used `-- Converting the date into quarters
select a.*,  
CASE
    WHEN a.STime BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '05:59:59' THEN 'Q1'
    WHEN a.STime BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '11:59:59' THEN 'Q2'
    WHEN a.STime BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '17:59:59' THEN 'Q3'
    ELSE 'Q4'
END AS QuarterOfTheDay
FROM (SELECT convert(char(8), start_time, 108) as STime from MyTable)  a; 
`

Comment: in your code, I got an error: `Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 36
'HOUR' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: `HOUR` is definitely a MySQL function.  You have tagged this a MySQL question - what database are you using?

Comment: SQL server 12, wrongly tagged MySQL, will remove it... thanks for reminding

Comment: @loveR Please find my updated answer which utilised SQL Server's `DATEPART`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get a number betwen 1 and 4:

```
(extract(Hour from start_time) / 6) + 1
```

Edit:

Extracting the hour is different for SQL Server

```
datepart(hour, Start_Time)/6+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the way I wanted output from SQL Server 12:

```
-- Converting the date into quarters 

select a.*, 
CASE     
     WHEN a.STime BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '05:59:59' THEN 'Q1'     
     WHEN a.STime BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '11:59:59' THEN 'Q2' 
     WHEN a.STime BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '17:59:59' THEN 'Q3'     
     ELSE 'Q4' 
END AS QuarterOfTheDay 
FROM (SELECT convert(char(8), start_time, 108) as STime from MyTable) a;
```

I was not able to use the other two answers as HOUR() returned as error :

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 36
 'HOUR' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Comment: Of course, HOUR is invalid syntax in SQL Server, you should use correct tags :-) See my modified answer

Comment: The example is technically wrong...  `BETWEEN` is inclusive which is the equivalent of `WHEN a.STime >= '00:00:00' a.STime <= '05:59:59'.`  But this does not include the milliseconds of datetime which will result in an incorrect answer; for example if an entry occurs at 05:59:59.001.  It may be preferable to write this out fully, for example: `WHEN a.STime >= '00:00:00' AND a.STime < '06:00:00'`